# Python: recursion and return

Tags: python, recursion, scope

As an exercise, I was trying to make a script that would give me the sum of the items in a list but without using SUM or FOR/WHILE loops.

I ended up solving it with:

```
def addition(data, total=0):
    if data:
        total += data.pop()
        return total if data == [] else addition(data, total)

print(addition([1,2,3,1,2,1]))
```

This works well and returns '10', but my initial approach was:

```
def addition(data, total=0):
    if data != []:
        total += data.pop()
        addition(data, total)
    return total

print(addition([1,2,3,1,2,1]))
```

and this second bit of code returns '1' instead of '10'. I can't figure out why the two approaches aren't doing the same thing or even where the second example comes up with the '1' as it enters the final loop with data = [] and totals = 10, I'm guessing that I'm missing some rule regarding how variable scopes work?

(as explained in the answers below, it had nothing to do with variable scope so I changed the title to reflect the issue, for anyone happening on this in the future)

Comment: This is not really related to your question (which is well answered below), but I'd like to add that Python doesn't offer any benefit to tail recursion, so you could simplify your function a bit to be something like `if data: return data.pop() + addition(data)` with `else: return 0` as the base case. You wouldn't need the `total` argument at all, since the actual addition happens with the return values.

Comment: hey @Blckknght, still a bit new and I think I was looking at recursion the wrong way but looking at your example, I think I got it now. I was looking at it more like a while loop, where every iteration would be processed linearly and the output of one loop would be the input to the next until the base case was reached to break the loop but, that's not the case in recursion, is it? It's more like unpacking the same expression within itself until a known base case is reached and then everything gets solved from the inner most nested expression outwards. Thank you, that helped

Comment: @Blckknght
`def fib(data):
    if data > 1:
        return fib(data-1) + fib(data-2)
    elif data == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

print(fib(15))`

yup, got the idea and I now totally understand why the return statements were also necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `total += data.pop()` in a child function, the variable `total` is not changed in the calling function because integers are immutable.

Only the first element to be popped, 1, is added to `total` before the function returns. For it to do the same thing, you would want to replace `addition(data, total)` with `return addition(data, total)`.

Comment: Tested, you are correct. I did not realize copies were being made when I was calling the function again.

Comment: To be clear, the variable `data` is not copied because it is a list, only `total` is.

Comment: @SzombatfalviHunorGellèrt uh.. I actually think that part of the answer is wrong. No copies are made: `data = [1,2,3,1,2,1]; print(addition(data)); print(data)` will print an empty list.

Comment: @kazemakase `data` is not copied, `total` is. Integers are immutable

Comment: @yinnonsanders Not even `total` is copied. Integers do not need to be copied because they are immutable. In fact, it's [impossible to copy](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dd7128f18e0a70eb6fa72a9c652aa482) them.

Answer (score 2):

The result is not related to variable scopes. Your first implementation returns the result of the recursive calls to `addition`. The second implementation does not. Thus, `total` is not updated after the first element.

```
def addition(data, total=0):
    if data != []:
        total += data.pop()
        # addition(data, total)  # return value not used; this line does not modify result
    return total  # total = 0 + first element
```

Both functions `pop` from the original list and therefore modify the input data. Consider an alternative like this:

```
def addition(data, total=0):
    if data:
        return addition(data[1:], total + data[0])
    return total
```

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, always add print statements ;)

```
def addition(data, total=0):
   if data!= []:
      total += data.pop()
      print("Total is " + str(total))
      addition(data, total)
   return total
```

`addition([1,2,3])` returns:

```
Total is 3
Total is 5
Total is 6
3
```

Do you see where the mistake is now? :) You don't do anything with the return value of `addition(data, total)` - this code does nothing to result. What you can do is return this value:

```
def addition(data, total=0):
    if data!= []:
        total += data.pop()
        return addition(data, total) 
    return total
```

Let's analyse what this code does: If `data` is empty - return `total` - we added everything already, nothing to do. If `data` is not an empty list, it will pop an element from data, add this value to `total` and repeat the process with a shorter list. Convince yourself that this code does indeed what you want.